# Getting message about docker wanting to create symlink every time I start Mac

Tags: docker, macos, startup, docker-desktop

(Almost) every time I start up my `Mac`, I get the the following message:

`Docker Desktop` wants to create `/var/run/docker.sock` symlink. Touch ID or enter your password to allow this.

[image]

Anybody knows how to get rid of this?

I allow it every time, but it keeps popping up every time I start up the Mac nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, I’m curious what it is, the docs don’t seem to mention it either. (Happens to me too after the latest update.)

Comment: Having the same problem on every startup on macOS and Docker 4.15.0 (93002).

Comment: Have you tried do switch it off and on again? No, seriously: Have you tried to uninstall it and reinstall it?

Comment: Exact same thing happens whenever I reboot my MacBook. issue isn't fixed as of Jan 19, '23.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is an issue open: [Docker asks to create a symlink after every OS restart. #6634](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6634)

Response is "should be fixed in the next release". The workaround of editing `~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json` and setting `"authDeclinedInstallSettings": false,` to `true` worked for me.

Comment: Still haven't fixed this as of Jan 5th, 2023

Comment: Note: this change to the settings.json file is required after updating docker; it seems the update just overwrites previous changes.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in version 4.17.0

Comment: @JayZhou The prompt keeps showing even though I had updated it to version `4.24.2`

Comment: @HongPhuc I changed to OrbStack a few months ago, and it works well. If you don't have to use any special features that only the docker desktop has, you can try it

Answer (score 7):

Yeah i really advise not to use the suggested "workaround" above concerning "authDeclinedInstallSettings"

While everything seem to work normal at a first glance,
i ended up this morning not beeing to able to build spring native images any more.
Because of the builder complaining that in cannot open the socket / connection any more.

At first I was totally puzzled, until backtracking that i did this change a couple of days ago.

Reverted it and now everything is back to normal .. of course that the nagging prompt is back